# How to print stack trace of StackOverflowException

Tags: .net, stack-trace, stack-overflow

I am developing a .Net 2.0 application in which a StackOverflowException occurs. Is there a way to print/log the stack trace before/during the application aborts?
This is a long running server-side process which would be hard to execute under a debugger.
I know that StackOverflowException can not be caught.

Comment: Does it generate a crash dump when it crashes? If so this might help http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/03/31/net-case-study-stackoverflow-exception-when-using-a-complex-rowfilter.aspx

Comment: Also you don't say what kind of application. If it is a web application I think you need to use the IIS Debug toolkit (although I don't know about IIS7)

Answer (score 4):

Use ADPlus (from Windows Debugging Tools) to force a dump on crash.

E.g.

```
adplus -hang -pn <process name> -o <dump file>
```

Comment: CW: Feel free to expand this with specifics (which I don't have to hand). While this doesn't cover the "before the application aborts" criterion, I don't think that is possible.