# C# StackOverflowException, Too many Method Calls

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I am getting a StackOverflowException during run time, I'm sure that I am calling too many methods, just can't pinpoint where this is happening. When I run the program the Exception occurs when the ***structurePath*** variable is declared.

*FolderContentManagement.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace VINA_BATCH.FFManagement
{   
class FolderContentManager : FileContentManager
{
    public int currIndex = 0;

    private VinaProcess.VProcess vproc = new VinaProcess.VProcess();
    private string structurePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "structures");
    private string structureExt = "*.pdbqt";
    private Dictionary<string, string> files = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public FolderContentManager() { }

    //Returns list of structures
    public string[] GetStructuresPath()
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(structurePath, structureExt);
    }


    public string[] GetStructureNames()
    {
        string[] structs = Directory.GetFiles(structurePath, structureExt);

        for(int i = 0; i < structs.Length; i++)
        {
            structs[i] = Path.GetFileName(structs[i]);
        }

        return structs;
    }

    public string GetCurrentStructureName()
    {
        string currPath = this.GetCurrentStructurePath();
        return Path.GetFileName(currPath);
    }

    public string GetCurrentStructurePath()
    {
        string currPath = "";
        string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(structurePath, structureExt);
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == currIndex)
                currPath = paths[i];
        }

        return currPath;
    }

    public string GetNextStructurePath(int index)
    {
        string[] names = GetStructureNames();
        string[] paths = GetStructuresPath();

        string nextPath = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == index)
                nextPath = paths[index + 1]; 
        }

        return nextPath;
    }

    /*
    public void CompilePathsFiles()
    {
        string workingPath = GetWorkingPath();
        string[] tempFiles = { GetCurrentStructureName(), findProtein(), "conf.txt", "log.txt" };

        for(int i = 0; i < tempFiles.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                files.Add(structurePath, tempFiles[i]);

            files.Add(workingPath, tempFiles[i]);                
        }

        MessageBox.Show(files.ToString());
    }
    */
    public void Move_RunRoutine()
    {
        /*
            - After conf.txt change copy to vina folder
            - Copy the rest of the working folder file to vina folder
            - Copy the current *.pdbqt file to the vina folder
        */



        string destination = vproc.GetVinaPath();

    }

    public void Move_OutRoutine()

   {
        /*
            - Once an iteration is done move the contents of the vina folder to out folder with the name of the *.pdbqt file 
        */
    }

}
}
```

**GetCurrentStructurePath()** is being called from another class like so. This is the only reference to *FolderContentManagement* that this class has.

```
contents[1] = String.Format("ligand = {0}", fcm.GetCurrentStructurePath());
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest to add a _break_ when you find the file searched in _GetCurrentStructurePath_

Comment: To be exact this is the line that is raising the exception                                 `private string structurePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "structures");`

Comment: Stackoverflows usually occur when you have an infinitely recursive function.

Comment: Please be aware that a StackOverflowException is similar to the proverbial last drop in a glass that make it overflow. It may not be a problem with that drop, it may instead be a problem with whatever filled the glass beforehand. In any case, most likely you have a recursive method somewhere, so go hunt for it.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm sure that I am calling too many methods`:

That is not why a `StackOverflowException` is thrown. There is no limit on how many methods an application can call.

Here is why a `StackOverflowException` is thrown; quoted from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when the execution stack overflows because it contains too many nested method calls.
>   StackOverflowException is thrown for execution stack overflow errors, typically in case of a very deep or unbounded recursion.

You say:

> When I run the program the Exception occurs when the structurePath variable is declared.

I do not think so. Here is a quick test you can do which proves the issue is elsewhere:

```
public class Test
{
    public string structurePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "structures");
}

var test = new Test();
var path = test.structurePath;
```

**To Troubleshoot**

Start by looking at

1. any recursive methods you may have and make sure they have a terminating condition
2. Check your properties and make sure the setter is not calling the getter like this:

   ```
   private int age;
   public int Age
   {
       get { return this.age; }
       // This is an easy mistake. It should be this.age (small a)
       set { this.Age = value; } 
   }
   ```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733878/how-to-debug-a-stackoverflowexception-in-net) answer for more ideas on troubleshooting.