# StackOverflowException when call DataContext.SubmitChanges()

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

I am using `Linq-To-SQL` to perform inserts into a table that has the following definition (omitting some superfluous fields):

```
ID int not null
SourceName varchar(100)
Version int not null
TransactionID int not null
Xml nvarchar(max)
```

`ID`, `SourceName`, `Version` and `TransactionID` form the primary key for the table. There are no foreign keys or constraints.

I create a `DataContext` for my database and then create a new record. When I call `SubmitChanges` on my DataContext a `StackOverflowException` is thrown.

```
using (var ctx = new MyDataContext(connectionString))
{
    var row = new MyTable
    {
        ID = 1
        , SourceName = "foo"
        , Version = 1
        , TransactionID = 0 //this is the weird part - see below
        , Xml = "some xml string"
    }

    ctx.MyTable.InsertOnSubmit(row);
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

However, after lots of value substituting and trial and error the `StackOverflowException` does not get thrown if I change `TransactionID` to 1 (I initially assumed the Xml field was somehow overflowing).

I was using 0 just for the scenarios where for a transaction id could not be identified some reason.

I obviously googled this but the only related issue I found was caused by a foreign key relationship.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? I have a work around but am curious what could be the cause.

I am using .Net 3.5 and SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Listing at least the part of the stack trace that VS *can* retrieve would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately not. When I try to view it VS says something like it cannot be evaluated. I am literally just given the exception message. Very strange issue.

Comment: How about the Call Stack window?

Comment: Empty too. The exception just completely blows the process out of the water.

Comment: This might be helpful, then: [How to print stack trace of StackOverflowException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591406/how-to-print-stack-trace-of-stackoverflowexception)

Comment: @ErikHeemskerk Thanks. I will take a look when I finally fix my umpteen other issues.